# How do I evaluate or execute string interpolation in Elixir?

Tags: string, elixir, string-interpolation

Suppose I construct a string using [`sigil_S`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#strings):

```
iex> s = ~S(#{1 + 1})
"\#{1 + 1}"
```

How do I then get Elixir to evaluate that string or perform interpolation, as if I had entered the literal `"#{1 + 1}"`?

In other words, how do I get it to evaluate to `"2"`?

I know I can use `EEx` instead (e.g. `EEx.eval_string "<%=1 + 1%>"`) but I'm curious if there's a way to do it using just 'plain' string interpolation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lower case sigils support interpolation. More about it [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html):

> If the sigil is lower case (such as sigil_x) then the string argument will allow interpolation. If the sigil is upper case (such as sigil_X) then the string will not be interpolated.

So, you can use sigil `~s` to evaluate interpolation in place:

```
~s(#{1 + 1}) #=> "2"
~S(#{1 + 1}) #=> "\#{1 + 1}"
```

Or you can just simply use string interpolation:

```
"#{1 + 1}" #=> "2"
```

---

And, finally, if you want to evaluate your code written to a string variable dynamically, you can use [Code.eval_string/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3):

```
s = "\"\#{1 + 1}\""               #=> "\"\#{1 + 1}\""
s |> Code.eval_string |> elem(0)  #=> "2"
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't so clear in my question. I was aware of `~s`. Anyway, I was able to do this using `Code.eval_string ~s("#{s}")` (note the extra quotes). What I'm trying to do is a little more involved though—essentially I want to be able to do what `EEx.eval_string/3` does but using string interpolation syntax, e.g. `my_eval ~S(Hello, #{name}), [name: "world"]`.

`Code.eval_string ~s("Hello, #{name}")` works when name is defined but `Code.eval_string ~s("#{s}")` fails with `undefined function name/0`. Any further ideas?

Comment: Ah. `Code.eval_string` also accepts bindings. I was able to do what I wanted to do using: `Code.eval_string ~s("#{s}"), [name: "world"]`

Comment: New URL for the documentation : https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `Code` module which has the function `eval_string` so just swap out `EEx` for `Code`

```
Code.eval_string "1 + 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could use [`Code.eval_string/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3):

```
{result, _} = Code.eval_string "1 + 1"
result
#⇒ 2
```

the word “interpolation” you’ve used in the question makes me think about you were looking for simple:

```
"#{1 + 1}"
#⇒ "2"
```

Sigil `~S` [*escapes*](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#interpolation-and-escaping-in-sigils) the string given, that’s why you’ve got sharp sign escaped.